# fst является функцией одной переменной f, чтобы применить к строке s (fst будет одним из двух функций Vertmirror или Hormirror) пример на bash

Tags: bash

Задание с Codewars https://www.codewars.com/kata/56dbe0e313c2f63be4000b25/train/shell
Если я правильно понял - то что написано ниже должно пониматься так
oper(fct, s)  - смутило что аргументы в функцию тут прописаны в скобках - а это bash
там так не передаются аргументы(наверное написано для разъяснения???)

где "fct" это функции которые я написал  - $1
"s" это строка(и) для теста               -$2

А вот мой "script"

```
#!/bin/bash

vertMirror() {
    vert_str=""
    str=$(echo "$2" | tr "," " ")
    for word in $str
    do
        rev_str=$(echo "${word}" | rev)
        vert_str+="${rev_str}\r"

    done
    echo "${vert_str%??}"
}


horMirror() {
    hor_st=""
    str=$(echo "$2" | tr "," " ")
    declare -a array
    array=($(echo ${str}))
    count=${#array[*]}  
    for ((i=count -1;i>=0;i--)); do
        hor_st+="${array[i]}\r"
    done
    echo "${hor_st%??}"

}
```

А вот тут не знаю как запустить весь скрипт - написал в oper() вот такие строки
Ответ с сервера --- пустая строка
Неправильно присваиваю в переменную функции???
Не знаю что нужно прописать в oper()

```
oper() {
   fct=$(vertMirror "$2") # vertMirror "$2"
   fct=$(horMirror "$2")  # horMirror "$2"
   
}
oper $1 $2

Подскажите пожайлуста "куда или как копать!!!!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понял, суть задания в том чтобы написать две функции, которые каким-то образом(по разному) преобразуют полученную строку.
И написать еще одну функцию которая на основе аргументов, переданных скрипту выполнит ту или иную функцию. Упрощенно это пример выглядит так:

```
#!/bin/bash

# сохраняем аргументы скрипта в соотв. переменных
f=$1 #имя функции
s=$2 #строка для обработки

ver(){
    local data=$1 # сохраняем аргумент(1-й) функции в переменную data
    echo  "ver-$data"
}

hor(){
    local data=$1 # сохраняем аргумент(1-й) функции в переменную data
    echo  "hor-$data"
}

opt(){
    local   func=$1 # сохраняем 1-й аргумент функции в переменную func
    local   data=$2 # сохраняем 2-й аргумент функции в переменную data
    $func "$data"
}

opt $f "$s"
```

Ну и очевидно что функция opt избыточна, можно просто так:

```
#!/bin/bash

# сохраняем аргументы скрипта в соотв. переменных
f=$1 #имя функции
s=$2 #строка для обработки

ver(){
    local data=$1 # сохраняем аргумент(1-й) функции в переменную data 
    echo  "ver-$data"
}

hor(){
    local data=$1 # сохраняем аргумент(1-й) функции в переменную data
    echo  "hor-$data"
}

$f "$s"
```

Обратите внимание что переменные с данными(строка) обернуты в "". Т.к. данные могут содержать пробелы, а в названиях функций пробелы не допускаются. Тест:

```
$ ./test ver 123
ver-123

$ ./test hor 123
hor-123
```

Comment: Вот как это реализовано в Python def vert_mirror(s):
    return "\n".join(line[::-1] for line in s.split("\n"))

def hor_mirror(s):
    return "\n".join(s.split("\n")[::-1])

def oper(fct, s):
    return fct(s)

Comment: В python в функции oper(fct, s):return fct(s) - просто возвратить fct(s) - сразу происходит обработка обоих функций - а как в bash сделать так же - если fct прописываю - ругается

Comment: У вас проблемма в том что вы используете пустой параметр(`$2`) в функциях vertMirror и horMirror.
Вы вероятно путаете параметры скрипта и параметры функции, это не одно и тоже. $2 внутри функции это второй параметр, переданный функции. Посмотрите как показано в моём примере, 2-й аргумент скрипта(строка) внутри функций обрабатывается как 1-й параметр. Т.к. я передаю в функции только один аргумент(строку).

Comment: horMirror(){ echo horMirror-$1; }
verMirror(){ echo verMirror-$1; }
oper() {
   $1 "$2";
}
oper $1 $2  прописал ниже 2-х функций - но проверка с сервера показала пустую строку, не как не пойму как это сделать в bash.Параметры функции - с чем она вызывается - в функциях я использую "$2" - знаю что это строка(проверочная берётся из задания) - $1 это fct, Но мои функции 2-е первые принимают только один параметр "$2"  --- я их проверял --- они выдают правильные ответы, В python просто прописывается в oper(fct, s):return fct(s)  - а в bash --- НУ ПРОСТО НЕ ДОГОНЯЮ!!!

Comment: Расписал подробнее.

Comment: Только вот echo  "hor-$data" и echo  "hor-$data" не нужны в функциях(я так понял что это для примера) .БЛАГОДАРЮ!!!!Проверь я правильно поставил ОЦЕНКУ твоей помощи.